# How to transmit value of adc stm32 Bluetooth low energy x-nucleo?

Tags: eclipse, bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, cubemx

I use the "Nucleo idb04a1 bluetooth low energy" extention. I downloaded the CubeMX from ST website. I ran the example project and it works fine.

Now I want to transmit through UART the value of ADC pin of the board STM32 f401RE and read the value of my weight and flex sensors for my project and see the result on my smartphone.
Which libraries, functions and pins I need to use for my project ?
I use CubeMX to configure pins of my board.

Great regards

Comment: So you want to read the value of the weight/flex sensors, send them through UART to your extension board and then use Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) to send it to your smartphone which will have an application to receive the data ?

Comment: Are you also looking at libraries to create your application on the smartphone?